# Upgrading Squeeze to Wheezy: Unresolved Dependencies

Tags: dovecot, debian-wheezy

So I upgraded from Squeeze to Wheezy and Dovecot failed to resolve dependencies:

```
dpkg: error processing dovecot-pop3d (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-core
 dovecot-gssapi
 dovecot-sqlite
 dovecot-pgsql
 dovecot-sieve
 dovecot-mysql
 dovecot-imapd
 dovecot-common
 dovecot-ldap
 dovecot-pop3d
```

After searching around on the internet I found the following article: http://www.itwire.com/opinion-and-analysis/open-sauce/59796-dovecot-fails-during-wheezy-upgrade Now I've got two options:

- make it work somehow
- remove the dovecot install and upgrade it to dovecot 2.0

Has anyone used either of these approaches or does anyone have a better idea to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by running:

`doveconf -n -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf > dovecot-2.conf`

It will show you the error messages and which dovecot currently fails. For me this was SSL:

```
doveconf: Error: ssl enabled, but ssl_cert not set
doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf: ssl enabled, but ssl_cert not set
```

I ended up uncommenting the SSL section and setting the correct paths to the certificates. After this came the following error:

```
[....] Starting IMAP/POP3 mail server: dovecotFatal: service(auth) access(/usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth) failed: No such file or directory
 failed!
```

I had a /usr/lib/dovecot/auth file but not a dovecot-auth file. So I created a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/dovecot/auth /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-auth
```

This fixed my issues.